# Codigo em C não mostra lista completa

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main()
{

    struct aluno{

        char nome[30];
        int n_matricula;
        char curso[30];
    };

    struct aluno alunos[5];
    int numero;

    for(numero=1; numero<=5; numero++)
    {
        printf("Nome do aluno %i.................: ",numero);   gets(alunos[numero].nome);
        printf("Curso do aluno %i................: ",numero);   gets(alunos[numero].curso);
        printf("Numero da matricula do aluno %i..: ",numero);   scanf("%i",&alunos[numero].n_matricula);
        printf("\n\n\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n_____________________________________________\n\n");
    printf("Alunos:\n\n");

    for(numero=1; numero<=5; numero++)
    {
        printf("\n----------------------\n");   printf("%s",alunos[numero].nome);   printf("\n----------------------\n");
        printf("\n----------------------\n");   printf("%s",alunos[numero].curso);  printf("\n----------------------\n");
        printf("\n----------------------\n");   printf("%s",alunos[numero].n_matricula);    printf("\n----------------------\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não elabore questões apenas com código. Detalhe o seu problema o mais possível para que quem leia a sua pergunta consiga perceber. Posso desde já dizer que tem alguns erros como usar `%s` para ler numeros, e misturar `gets` com `scanf`

Comment: Obrigado por avisar

Comment: O índice de um array em C parte de 0 e não de 1.

Comment: Antes de mais nada, veja [como e porque aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterações em C se iniciam em 0, por isso o `for` fica:

```
for(numero = 0; numero < 5; numero++)
```

Em: `printf("%s",alunos[numero].n_matricula);` é `printf("%d",alunos[numero].n_matricula);`

Para misturar `scanf` e `gets` você deve ter de descarregar a entrada, veja: https://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/LaproI/Fflush/CorrigeScanfGets.html

Além disso `gets` está *deprecated* e não deve ser utilizada.

Abaixo como você pode fazer, utilizando `fgets` em tudo, com `atoi` para `n_matricula`:

```
int main()
{
    struct aluno{

        char nome[30];
        int n_matricula;
        char curso[30];
    };

    struct aluno alunos[5];
    char matricula[10];
    int numero;

    for(numero=0; numero<5; numero++)
    {
        printf("Nome do aluno %i.................: ",numero);   fgets(alunos[numero].nome, 30, stdin);
        printf("Curso do aluno %i................: ",numero);   fgets(alunos[numero].curso, 30, stdin);
        printf("Numero da matricula do aluno %i..: ",numero);   fgets(matricula, 10, stdin);
        alunos[numero].n_matricula = atoi(matricula);
        printf("\n\n\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n_____________________________________________\n\n");
    printf("Alunos:\n\n");

    for(numero=0; numero<5; numero++)
    {
        printf("\n----------------------\n");   printf("%s",alunos[numero].nome);   printf("----------------------\n");
        printf("\n----------------------\n");   printf("%s",alunos[numero].curso);  printf("----------------------\n");
        printf("\n----------------------\n");   printf("%d",alunos[numero].n_matricula);    printf("\n----------------------\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```